Do I need a MOV in front of AC/DC supply
I am working on unit that needs to pass IEC6100-4-5, see table below:

I have an AC to DC power supply, 100-230VAC, 50/60Hz, 5V/6A.
AC/DC power supply can pass these tests without a MOV mounted in front, as per the test results shared with me.
On the other end, manufacturer is stating that "Having a MOV in front of it might be a good idea".
Having in mind that MOV is usually preceded with fuse, and I don't have the ability to change the fuse as device will be sealed, what is a recommended way of dealing with this design problem?
Is there a circuit in mind that I am missing?
Are line surges expected to be higher than ones stated by the standard, in practice?

What's a "MOV"?

You appear to be missing a zero from the surge specification reference number. It depends which lightning protection zone your power supply is mounted in.

Ofc 61000-4-5. LPZ0B

@jonathanjo Metal Oxide Varistor.

What is your use case? In a lot of industries the older generation of EEs won't use anything that doesn't have a MOV, even if its replaced with a TVS, GDT, or zener

You could buy an MOV with a built-in thermal fuse. That way, if the MOV fails short circuit, it will disconnect itself permanently, and the rest of the power supply carries on as normal.

If your power supply passes already, I don't see any reason to add more components.
Sooner or later, one of your customers will experience a surge above the IEC61000-4-5 levels and the power supply breaks. If that customer support call/warranty claim is worth a lot to you, additional protection could be considered. The levels in IEC6100-4-5 are set to capture most but not all cases experienced as it's a cost-risk tradeoff.

MOV can fail too. With higher withstanding voltage though, and the point was if there is a fuse I can't replace, then damage will be contained within the FUSE/MOV rather than the rest of the circuit, which is fair point!
